# Question about the (exactness of the) curvature form of a Hermitian metric

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, line-bundles

From the local computation: $$\partial \bar{\partial} \log h =(\partial + \bar{\partial})\bar{\partial}\log h = d \bar{\partial} \log h,$$ it appears that the curvature form of a Hermitian metric is always exact, hence trivial in the De Rham cohomology class.

> Could anyone tell me what's wrong with the computation?

Comment: The form above is closed but generally not exact; it represents $c_1(X)$ (or $c_1(L)$ for a line bundle $L \to X$, or etc.) in $H^2(X)$. The difference of two such forms for $h$ and $h'$ is exact, which effectively means that the Chern curvature is independent as a cohomology class of the choice of $h$. More directly, $h$ is a local section above; you've shown that the form is locally exact, which is just the same as being closed. For a general nontrivial line bundle, there's no global nonzero section $h$.

Comment: I got it！thanks！